# estoy creando un formulario de contacto en angular pero la hora de presionar el submit este no hace nada

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, submit

***estoy creando un formulario de contacto en angular pero  la hora de presionar el submit este no hace nada***

```
<form #formContact="ngForm" action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i><input class="input-border" type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.name" required>
        <span class="form-error" *ngIf="name.touched && !name.valid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i> Name is empty.</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label><br>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-at"></i><input class="input-border" type="email" name="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email" required>
        <span class="form-error" *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i> Email is empty or invalid.</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="message">Message</label><br>
        <i class="fa-regular fa-message"></i><textarea name="message" #message="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.message" required></textarea>
        <span class="form-error" *ngIf="message.touched && !message.valid"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i> Message is empty</span>
       
    </p> 
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" [disabled]="!formContact.form.valid" />
        
</form>
```

quizás sea un error en el servicio de correos o quizás el hecho de que no este subida a internet aun

Comment: ¡Bienvenido(a) a SOes!. Vendría mejor que especifiques más tu pregunta mostrando tu código completo y también lo que estás intentado resolver a más detalle. Te invito a que visites el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y mires [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) dándonos un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, ¡Saludos!. ¿Y el servicio? ¿El Typescript? ¿Qué error te sale en el log?

Answer (score 0):

creo que te falta la directiva (click) en el boton:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" [disabled]="!formContact.form.valid" (click)="submit()" />
```

y en tu archivo ts:

```
public submit() {
//TO DO
}
```

Comment: sabes cual seria el método que debo usar en typescript para hacer que se envié el correo o tendría que usar Node directamente con angular?

Comment: ¿Quieres que habrá la página de Gmail en otra ventana o te refieres a enviar el correo desde tu web app? Si es el segundo caso tendrás que usar alguna librería de node.